# How can I improve this riddle?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> Baby boy bleating, "now!"
>   Crazy cat cooling off.
>   Daring dunce duelling foe.
>
> Lazy Lance lighting rock.
>   Plucky pleb playing, how?
>   Three threads thrashing you.

This riddle isn't up to my usual standards. There's a tag I often like to add, but it hasn't worked out this time. Nevertheless, can you solve it and get the point?

Comment: First half all the words start with B, C, D (except the last ones) and in the second half - L, P, T.

Comment: r/lifeprotips is obviously what rand was going for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the missing tag is

> Rhyme

and it didn't work this time because

> you tried to finish each alliterative line with words that look like they should rhyme, but don't.  Instead, you inserted a word that rhymes with the -ough word. 
>  bough (rhymes with 'now')
>  cough (rhymes with 'off')
>  dough (rhymes with 'foe')
>  lough (rhymes with 'rock')
>  plough (rhymes with 'how')
>  through (rhymes with 'you')

Comment: Yay, you got it! At least you got the essential idea. Your choice of words in inverted commas and brackets could be improved, based on the question ...

Comment: Ah, I totally missed how the current line endings fit into the scheme. I thought they were just random placeholders. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Well Rand al'Thor (may I call you the Dragon Reborn?), you do love to add the tag

> Word. This is especially obvious, since the last word of every line has a different starting letter than the words before it. So, since the last words of every line are messed up, (we'd like to keep that alliteration), I've opted in some optional words in place of them.

On line one

> change "now!" to "Bah!" Bah is a common exclamation for crying.

On line two

> Change "off" to "carefully" or some other c word here. I'm lost here

On line three

> Change "foe" to "dangerously". If a dunce is dueling, it would make it dangerous, right?

On line four

> Change "rock" to "lamp"; it makes more sense that way.

On line five

> Change "how?" to peacefully. How is he playing? Well, he's playing peacefully.

On line six

> Change "you" to "thee", because they are synonyms.

Well, I don't know if I'm on the right track at all, but this seems to fit.

Comment: Sorry, nope :-) Good try, but the answer is more 'unique' than this.